# How do I display a CMS static block in my Magento header

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

In the magento "Admin > CMS > Static Blocks" I have created a new static block. I am trying to figure out how to display it in my header template. I am not having success. I am quite new to magento and don't really have a deep understanding of it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_banner')->toHtml() ?>
```

product_banner is the id(identifier) of your static block you want to call.replace product_banner with your id.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did exactly what I wanted!